# Apache RewriteMap syntax for full URLs

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a rewrite map with around 5000 entries like this:

```
http://www.example.com/some-random-url http://www.example.net/some-random-url
```

For each entry the source domain, eg. `example.com` above, is the same, but the destination domain, `example.net` above, is a different domain. The path pattern also changes with each URL (I wish I could post more than 2 links!)

What I have so far is:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteMap examplemap "txt:/etc/httpd/conf/redirect.txt"

RewriteCond ${examplemap:$1} !=""
RewriteRule ^/(.*) ${examplemap:$1} [redirect=permanent,last]
```

I cannot seem to get the correct syntax for the `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` directives and would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the key of the rewrite map to be the current URL and then find the matching redirect.

Then you can use :

`RewriteRule .* ${examplemap:http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}}`